# What are the proper steps to install Symfony2 on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-10.04

I already installed LAMP, but I can't get Symfony2 to install. This is what I tried:

```
php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition /var/www/georgecampean/Symfony '2.5.*'
Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.5.6)
  - Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.5.6)
    Loading from cache

Created project in /var/www/georgecampean/Symfony
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package php could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package php could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-bundle ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle[v1.2.0].
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle v1.2.0 requires php >=5.3.2 -> no matching package found.
  Problem 4
    - doctrine/orm v2.4.6 requires php >=5.3.2 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/orm v2.4.5 requires php >=5.3.2 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/orm v2.4.4 requires php >=5.3.2 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/orm v2.4.3 requires php >=5.3.2 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/orm v2.4.2 requires php >=5.3.2 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/orm v2.4.1 requires php >=5.3.2 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/orm v2.4.0 requires php >=5.3.2 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/orm v2.3.6 requires php >=5.3.2 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/orm 2.3.5 requires php >=5.3.2 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/orm 2.3.4 requires php >=5.3.2 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/orm 2.3.3 requires php >=5.3.2 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/orm 2.3.2 requires php >=5.3.2 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/orm 2.3.1 requires php >=5.3.2 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/orm 2.3.0 requires php >=5.3.2 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/orm 2.2.3 requires php >=5.3.2 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for doctrine/orm ~2.2,>=2.2.3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/orm[2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your php version. Symfony needs php 5.3.3 minimum. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html

Comment: I'd also add that 10.04 is EOL - which may be relevant here.

Comment: Your link is for V2.6.  The question shows V2.5.6 and the messages refer to php 5.3.2 being required.  However, you appear to have spotted the missing dependency.